# Has there ever been a time or place where high-level bridge was played with no convention cards? If so, what did it look like?

Tags: bridge

I’ve been digging through the internet, working through curiosity about bridge’s requirement that all partnerships have a convention card. I’ve learned a few things:

1. The intuition that open conventions make the game into something other than it ought to be is pretty common for new players
2. Veterans respond that getting rid of convention cards would make the game random, or random*er*, or at least make it into something entirely different from what it is, because bidding would become mostly destructive without open conventions
3. Competitive bridge has slowly tightened on how much destructive bidding it allows.

I take it that they’re probably right and the game would be worse with secret conventions. It would be so good for my brain, though, to know what that worse game actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

At the very beginning, bridge was played with no conventions.  While this was not a codified rule, the original expectation at the very beginning of the 20th century was that all bids were natural, and this expectation was socially enforced.  It was even questionable whether partners could agree beforehand whether a bid (say a natural 2/1 change of suit) was forcing or not.

When the takeout double was introduced - clearly this is an improvement on the natural meaning - rarely does one want to double an opposition opening 1 bid for penalties - it was quite a matter of debate whether such an agreement should be legal or not.  Many bridge players didn't accept it, or allowed it but thought it unethical and refused to use it.  However, it was so clearly superior and an advance in the game that it became accepted and universally adopted.

The Vanderbilt Club was introduced in 1929 but rarely adopted, Blackwood in 1933, and Stayman in 1945.  Most players played no conventions other than Blackwood in the 1940s, and Stayman did not become widely adopted until the mid 1950s.  (The earliest Goren books did not have Stayman!)  There were simply no conventions, and hence no need for a convention card.  There was a strongly enforced social expectation that you would play exactly the same bidding systems and conventions everyone else did, though exactly what conventions those were varied somewhat by country.

Beginning in the late 1950s, once partnership agreements started diverging from each other, bridge organizations started codifying rules about when one's partner had to "Alert" one's bid.  (When you make certain conventional bids, your partner says "Alert", letting the opponents know that your bid has a meaning they might not have expected.)  As far as I can tell, there was always, even prior to this, the expectation that one could ask the opponents what their bids meant.  (Back in the 1920s, one could ask the opponents whether they played informatory doubles - as takeout doubles were then called.)  Convention cards were adopted AFTER alerts, sometime in the 1960s, and not everywhere at once, once there were enough divergent conventions that having a written document to inform the opponents in addition to verbal alerts and explanations became helpful.

As long as it's been the case that coming up with your own conventions wouldn't get you shunned, it's been expected that your opponents know your agreements with your partner.

Comment: You have completely missed the *Culbertson era*. Ely Culbertson's first book on Contract Bridge bidding: Edition 1 of the **Contract Bridge Blue Book - was published in 1930 and, with the second edition, "ran through eighty-five consecutive printings ... from 1930 to the end of 1932 .... " Although he didn't invent it, Culbertson was the most vocal early proponent of the **Approach Forcing principle, whereby non-jump new suit bids by Responder are a one-round force. This absolutely is a bidding convention; and I believe predates Vanderbilt's invention of the Contract Bridge rules in late 1925.

Comment: [Link for the quote above](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.166624/page/n13/mode/2up) on page *viii* of Culbertson's **Contract Bridge Blue Book of 1933**

Comment: Florence Irwin's 1920 book [**Master Auction - Auction For Those Who Know It**](https://archive.org/details/masterauctionauc00irwi/page/30/mode/2up) is a complete bidding system played without the "One Double" - his name for today's Takeout Double - specifying specific sequences for, in particular, competitive auctions. This book predates Vanderbilt's Contract Bridge Rules by about 5 years. Irwin's lengthy screed against the One Double is particularly humorous, in light of subsequent development.

Comment: IIRC, Norman Squire's books (e.g. The Theory of Bidding, Bidding Today, Bidding at Bridge) had very little in the way of conventions, too.  However, the OP was asking if people ever have played bridge with "secret conventions" or no concept of "open conventions".